# Sonar Error - Can not execute Sonar: Fail to extract sonar-runner-batch.jar: No space left on device

Tags: mysql, linux, jenkins, sonarqube

Sonar was running fine along with jenkins for 6 months without any failures. Since last week, I am seeing the below error for some jenkins jobs causing the jobs to fail.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project Project: Can not execute Sonar: Fail to extract sonar-runner-batch.jar: No space left on device -> [Help 1]
```

Sonar is running on linux host. I could see sonar-runner-batch jars piled up under /tmp folder. To make sonar work again I need to perform the below steps.

1. Clear all files under /tmp folder.
2. Stop Sonarqube server by running ./sonar.sh stop.
3. Restart MYSQL DB.
4. Start Sonarqube by running ./sonar.sh start.

Sonar runs fine. But issues comes up again in like a couple of days. I have enough free space on my linux host.
I am using sonarqube 4.2. Please help with any inputs. I could not find any useful inputs from a google search.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Override the `SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/data/tmp"`.

Comment: That didn't work. `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-D/abc"` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Increased the /tmp disk space. This is the only solution which worked for me. I have a scheduled job to clean up /tmp as well.

Answer (score -1):

I noticed the same issue some time ago, with my Sonar Runner 2.4. 
Up to about ~10GB of data in the /tmp folder. 
I don't see anything in the logs indicating it can't clean up the files.

In my particular case and my setup (OpenSuse 11.3, Hudson 1.395, SonarQube 3.7 and Sonar Runner 2.4) the issue appears and it's manageable.

Issue was reported on OCT 2013 and apparently fixed - http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4748

Are you sure you are using version 4.2?
Because they apparently fixed it in 4.0.

Try running it with version 5.0
Your issue should go away.